# Any folders on headless cent os safe to remove in /usr/share/ to regain desperate space?

Tags: centos, yum, disk-usage

I have an old web-server running apache that was installed with a small 8GB / drive for some reason.  Most things run on /home which is on another volume but there are some oddities I am having with it running out of space, was logs.  I created a script to kill httpd access logs after a time.

Then it started to run out of space (I am guessing because we have a veeam agent now running on this machine)....so the fix here is yum clean all and it clears the cache in (var /cache? don't recall)....but that fills up again in a few hours even with keepcache=0 in yum.cfg.

So now my last move is to figure out how to get more space, checking folders a big chunk of space is taken up in:
/usr/share

```
[root@web-server share]# du -xhs * | sort -rh
242M    fonts
217M    texlive
214M    locale
```

Can I remove these? clean them? move and sym link somehow?   It is a headless server but running with httpd not sure if that requires the fonts to be there and whatever the heck texlive is too.

Comment: Why do you have texlive and so many fonts installed on a web server?

Comment: I would LOVE to answer that for you but I am a software developer who got roped into being IT and didn't set this old server up, I inherited it.

Comment: Then before deleting anything you should try to determine what or who is using these. That said, I am guessing from the disk size that this is a VM? Why not resize the disk? It should be doable online.

Comment: it is a very old VM running in KVM which I have no experience in.   I wouldn't have the slightest clue how to do that.     The machine the KVM is running on is: LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Scientific Linux release 6.10 (Carbon)
Scientific Linux release 6.10 (Carbon) ...i am guessing old.

Comment: If `/var/cache/yum` is repeatedly filling up, you probably have a cron job running to update packages. If you can find and disable the cron job it sounds like you would be in good shape.

Comment: My root has a certbot update but not sure that does anything with packages. not sure if I knew the command I could grup where crontabs are stored and find the offending user.  Without that I could peek as each user in the crontab I guess.

Comment: Actually found cron jobs in /var/spool/cron and looked at each nothing is doing a yum anything that I can see.

Comment: For now I cleared enough space and told httpd logs to go somewhere else.  So I think it is okay even with that cache filling up always.